# Why does my print function give me output as "false"?

Tags: java

```
package Basics;

public class ch2_operators {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(64<6);
    }
}
```

Why does my print function give me output as "false" in the above code? The task of giving output as true and false is with boolean data type, right?

Comment: `64<4` is a boolean expression and it evaluates to `false`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: please change the title according to the question: "I have a question" could be any question title - "I'm learning Java" is also irrelevant to the question. I also suggest to take a look at [TOUR] and [ASK]

Comment: Your question suggests that you're just now learning the most basic concepts of Java programming. Since this site is not geared to work in place of an introduction to programming website, and since it is best to get this information from tutorials, you will probably want to start there. You can find links to great Java tutorials and other language resources in the [java info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) section of the [tag:java] tag. Start here: [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html).

Comment: Voting to close question as "resolved in a way not likely to help future readers"

Answer (score 2):

It is returning a boolean because you have passed a boolean expression by using the `<` operator. Your print statement will see it like this ***is 64 less than 4?***

So it would return a boolean

Answer (score 2):

According to Java programming language documentation of class `java.lang.System` `out` is a field of type `java.io.PrintStream` class that encapsulates the `println` method with one of its overloads accepting a `boolean` argument that is the type of comparison passed in when calling `System.out.println(64<6)`

Answer (score 2):

Note sure what you were trying to achieve but you're simply printing out the result of `64 < 4` which is `false` because 64 is not less than 4.

I'll assume that you're actually trying to print out the equation rather than the result in which case you'll have to print it out as a `String` by putting it in double quotes like this:

```
System.out.println("64 < 4");
```

This will print out `64 < 4`

Or to include the result:

```
System.out.println("64 < 4 = " + (64 < 4));
```

which will print out

```
64 < 4 = false
```

Answer (score 1):

> *'... the task of giving output as true and false is with boolean datatype right? ...'*

Correct, a *Boolean* data-type is used for depicting *true* or *false* values.
*[Wikipedia – Boolean data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type)*.

> *'... Why does my print function give me output as "false" ...'*

The reason your code works is because the result of your *[statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)* produces a *boolean* value.

This is similar to typing the following.

```java
String string;
System.out.println(string = "example");
```

The result of assigning a value to *string* is a *String* value, thus the text *"example"* is printed.